# Backplane Degraded on Dell Poweredge 2950 but non-critical?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-poweredge

My dell PE 2950 is today telling me that the Backplane is running in degraded mode but that the warning is non-critical.

My question is, what is the actual problem here? How can i find out? The openmanage tool is a bit vague to say the least!

Is there another bit of diagnostic i can run?

Also there is a yellow blinking light on one of the hard drive bays but the openmanage tool says all hard drives are fine. So what the dickins is going on here then?!

Any help very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OpenManage:

- Which Controller/backplane component is "Degraded"? (System - Storage - controller name)
- Checks logs in System - Logs (tab) - Hardware and Alert

If you can reboot your server, there is a Diagnostic CD Live from Dell.

Comment: On Connector 0 and connector 1 there is a warning triangle next to "Enclosure (Backplane)"

Comment: The log says Storage Drive 4: Drive slot sensor for storage, drive fault was asserted.

Comment: So the problem is disk in slot #4.

Comment: But the openmanage software says all the disks are fine!

Comment: Do you upgrade backplane and controller firmware and drivers? Then, if your server is covered by warranty, you can call Dell Support and explain your problem.

Comment: The server is out of warranty but that's cool, i think it is the HDD and i need a spare anyway so it's no problem ordering one. It's just a ambiguous error report in that it identifies the backplane as being the fault when as you say it probably is the HDD. I'll know for sure when the HDD turns up though! Thanks for your assistance and help!